# Possible to use visual flow in force.com sites

Tags: force.com-sites, visual-workflow

Is it possible to use visual flows embedded in visual force pages in a Force.com sites page? Also, using the visual force page with the embedded flow in a template?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, embedded flow in a Force.com site is definitely possible! I'm not 100% certain about the template, but it should theoretically be possible anywhere a Visualforce page can be used.
More information can be found on how to do this here.
https://automationchampion.com/2014/04/02/survey-powered-by-visual-workflow/